# Avoiding 'Unchecked Call' warning

Tags: java, generics

Say I have a factory interface with method `getTransformer(Item item)`
Item is an interface. Factory uses `instanceOf` to find correct transformer for Item to Entity. Transformer implements method  `S transform(T item)`.

Call to factory to get transformer is ok, but call `transformer.transform` is highlighted in IDE as unchecked call to `transform(T)`. How to avoid this?
i.e.

```
DTOTransformer dtoTransformer = dtoTransformerFactory.getTransformer(item);
ItemEntity itemEntity = dtoTransformer.transform(item); // this line has error
```

BTW, this was written on the fly for an interview which I'll have tomorrow. I'd like to know if this can be fixed or just use annotation unchecked to avoid compiler warnings.

```
public interface DTOTransformer<S extends ItemEntity, T extends Item> {

    S transform(T item);
}

public interface DTOTransformerFactory {

    DTOTransformer getTransformer(Item item);
}

public class DTOTransformerFactoryImpl implements DTOTransformerFactory {
    @Override
    public DTOTransformer getTransformer(Item item) {
        if (item instanceof RegularItemDTO) {
            return new RegularDTOTransformer();
        } else if (item instanceof SpecialItemDTO) {
            return new SpecialDTOTransformer();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No transformer for type:     " + item.getClass());
        }
    }
}

public class SpecialDTOTransformer implements     DTOTransformer<SpecialItemEntity, SpecialItemDTO> {
    @Override
    public SpecialItemEntity transform(SpecialItemDTO item) {
        SpecialItemEntity specialItemEntity = new SpecialItemEntity();
        specialItemEntity.setPrice(item.getPrice());
        specialItemEntity.setSku(item.getSku());
        specialItemEntity.setItem(item.getItem());
        specialItemEntity.setBuyAmount(item.getBuyAmount());
        specialItemEntity.setDiscountPrice(item.getDiscountPrice());

        return specialItemEntity;
    }
}
```

Comment: "this line has error" That line isn't in the code you've posted.

Comment: `DTOTransformer` is a raw type.

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem is, because you're talking about code you're not showing... but using raw types is going to be part of the problem.

Comment: Is it possible to make `DTOTransformerFactory` generic with type parameters `<S extends ItemEntity, T extends Item>`?

Comment: You can infer the generics into the Factory too

Comment: @AndyTurner fixed, formatting issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dtoTransformer` has no type arguments, so it has a raw type.

You need to add a few type arguments to your factory:

```
public interface DTOTransformerFactory {
    DTOTransformer<?, Item> getTransformer(Item item);
               // ^-------^ Here
}

public class DTOTransformerFactoryImpl implements DTOTransformerFactory {
    @Override
    public DTOTransformer<?, Item> getTransformer(Item item) {
                      // ^-------^ Here
        if (item instanceof RegularItemDTO) {
            return new RegularDTOTransformer<>();
                                         // ^^ Here, assuming RegularDTOTransformer is similarly parametrized.
        } else if (item instanceof SpecialItemDTO) {
            return new SpecialDTOTransformer<>();
                                         // ^^ Here.
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No transformer for type:     " + item.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
DTOTransformer<?, Item> dtoTransformer = dtoTransformerFactory.getTransformer(item);
ItemEntity itemEntity = dtoTransformer.transform(item); // this line has error
```